# Fill a specific column of datagridview from Informix vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, informix

I'm filling a DataGridView but I cannot find how to fill an specific column of the datagridview. The connection string and filling the table works fine.

I'm getting ID,Name,Surname,Country,Age from the database and inserting those in the table but I want the columns to be in a specific column because I also the table with data from another tables.

Example I want the column 2 to have the country, the column 3 to have the id, etc, in a different order than how it's stored in the database
How do I appoint in which column I want the data from the SQL to be stored?

```
Public Shared Sub listar(tipo As String, tabla As DataGridView)
         Try
    If connect() Then
            comando.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " & tipo
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery()
            dataAdapter.SelectCommand = comando
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, tipo)
            tabla.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(tipo)
            closeConn()
        End If
         Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox("ERROR")
        End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want the columns in a specific order then specify that order rather than using a wildcard, i.e. `*`, and letting the database decide the order.

Comment: Of course, if you're binding a `DataTable` to a `DataGridView` then how you display the data isn't controlled by the data source.  By default, what you see will match the data source but you can set the `DisplayIndex` of each column in the `DataGridView` so that the visual order is different to the logical order.

Comment: I'd appreciate an example of DisplayIndex, don't know it.                            Also changing the order from the SELET would require to make some complicated JOINs to get data from other tables and proabably it will ruin the method but it seems the simpliest way if I manage to make those joins thanks.

Comment: If you're not familiar with the `DisplayIndex` property then open the documentation and read about it.  VS has a Help menu for a reason.  If you need examples of its use, search online.  A site like this should be your last resort for information that you can't find otherwise.  If someone provides you with a keyword here, the first thing you should be doing is trying to find as much information on that keyword for yourself, not asking them to explain it.  This site is for the stuff you can't find or work out, not so that you don't have to do those things.

Comment: As for specifying column requiring complex joins, I don't see how that could be based on the code you've posted here.  It should be just a simple matter of replacing `"SELECT * FROM "` with `"SELECT Name, Country, ID, Surname, Age FROM "` or whatever is appropriate. If the issue is that you don't know what table you're querying so you don't know what columns you will be getting then I have to wonder what magic you expect to be able to perform to order columns when you don't know what they are.  You have to know what columns you want to get if you want to order them specifically.

Comment: What is `comando.ExecuteNonQuery()` doing. comando is a query so `.ExecuteNonQuery` is not appropriate.